# To calculate density of turtles distributed in three different areas of the world in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have three types of areas which are seperated using of color of patches. I want to calculate the mean of the population of turtles in each seperate area.

```
     count turtle-on patches with [pcolor = red] 
     count turtle-on patches with [pcolor = green]
     count turtle-on patches with [pcolor = blue]
```

These will give total number of turtles in each areas. Now I want to calculate turtle density in each area, I found somewhere the following way is used to calculate mean which I too followed according to my need. **But, here I am not getting how actually netlogo is calculating mean in this case.**

```
     let pop-count-red mean [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = red] 
     let pop-count-green mean [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = green]
     let pop-count-blue mean [count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = blue]
```

To calculate density we need number of people in an area, how netlogo is deciding red/green or blue patches areas. I mean, if 10 patches are of red color and each red patch is having different count of turtles on it, say for example 4turtle in one red patch, 2 turtle in another red patch, and so on.. So how it is being claclated. In real we have some defined unit to calculate so we simply divide and convert the unit as per our need.

Does "mean" here counts all turtles over red patches and divide them by 10.

Kindly help me in understanding this.

Comment: `[count turtles-here] of patches with [pcolor = red]` produces a list of counts.  (Try it at the command line and see.)  Your use of `mean` then produces the mean of this list of integers.

Comment: Alan's comment answers your posted question well, but I'm confused. Are you looking for the mean number of turtles in the area (mean density of each patch in the area), or are you looking for the density of turtles in the area (mean turtles per unit area)? Your code calculates the former, whereas true density would be [count turtles with [pcolor = red] / [count patches with [pcolor = red]]

Comment: thank you @Alan and @ Jesse001

Comment: @Jesse001 I want to calculate mean number of turtles in the area. (turtles in each patch). I am assuming 1patch equals to 1m square and want to know number of turtles per meter square per tick. so that I could know density of turtles per meter square.